# How to resolve "Essential container in task exited 0" without logs while launching task on AWS ECS cluster(Fargate type)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Actually things going on AWS:
"Essential container in task exited 0" without logs while launching task on AWS ECS cluster(Fargate type).
While deploying status goes into provisioning then to pending and then deprovisioning without any logs.

Steps to replicate:

1. I've .Net core application docker Image, which I pushed it to ECR.
2. Created task definition.
3. Created cluster.
4. Under cluster task, deployed task definition.

Output Expected:
ECS Cluster Task to be running, so I can access through public IP.

What I tried:

1. Retried to create cluster, task, task definition, not sure about what I can try. I am quite new to AWS.
2. Tried to allocate more CPU for task definition
3. Tried to deploy task definition as cluster service

Comment: If you run the same docker image locally, does it work?

Comment: yes @MarkB it works locally and even I deployed using AWS Beanstalk, it worked for me.